# How to convert a cassandra column value to a corresponding enum while querying

Tags: cassandra, cql

We have a cassandra column of type int, this value of int corresponds to value of a enum, is there a way to convert this int column to enum string while querying.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to make in the CQL itself, but Java driver supports [corresponding functionality](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/custom_codecs/extras/#enums) by using the `EnumOrdinalCodec` class (example from documentation):

```
enum State {INIT, RUNNING, STOPPING, STOPPED}

cluster.getConfiguration().getCodecRegistry()
        .register(new EnumOrdinalCodec<State>(State.class));

// schema: create table ordinal_example(id int PRIMARY KEY, state int)
session.execute("insert into ordinal_example (id, state) values (1, ?)", State.INIT);
```